# Why date_create_from_format always return false for me?

Tags: php, datetime

I am not a php coder, but the fates decided I need to pass through it.

```
$vote_date = date_create_from_format("H:i:s d.m.y", $last_vote_date_str); //$last_vote_date_str is 19:45:12 25.12.13

if ($vote_date == false)
    echo "<span style='color:red'>Error: Unable to parse the last vote date ($last_vote_date_str) -> (".date_format($vote_date, "Y-m-d H:i:s").")!<br><br></span><br>";
```

This is the output I always got: `Unable to parse the last vote date (19:45:12 25.12.13) -> ().")!`

I don't understand why this happens. I rechecked this date format many times and I think it's correct.
Any ideas?

P.S.
Result of echo `var_dump($last_vote_date_str);` is `string(26) "19:45:12 25.12.13"`

I tried to do this:

```
$temp_last_vote_str = "";
for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($last_vote_date_str); $j++)
if ($last_vote_date_str[j] == '0' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '1' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '2' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '3' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '4' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '5' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '6' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '7' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '8' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '9' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == ':' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == '.' || $last_vote_date_str[j] == ' ')
    $temp_last_vote_str += $last_vote_date_str[j];
$last_vote_date_str = $temp_last_vote_str;
```

But the last_vote_date_str becomes empty after it >_<

Comment: Post the output of `var_dump($last_vote_date_str);`.

Comment: Works for me: http://3v4l.org/rOMu0

Comment: @AmalMurali: in a way, he already did. :)

Comment: string(26) "19:45:12 25.12.13"

Comment: Since it says the string is 26 characters long, but we can only see 17, there must be extra characters in it. Maybe more spaces between the time and date?

Comment: When printing debugging output, it's best to put `<pre>...</pre>` around it, so that you see everything literally.

Comment: Umm I don't see there any spaces. Maybe it's something related with two-byte encoding and 26 is number of bytes?

Comment: Digits shouldn't be encoded with two bytes.

Comment: @Kosmos: Did you try [my suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20790535/1438393) below?

Comment: I tried, but can't check it fast now sinc epage becomes just html code. I read this date from another site after some data entered on my page.

Comment: What does `var_dump( trim(preg_replace('~[^\d:.]~', ' ', $last_vote_date_str)) );` return ?

Comment: it outputs: string(17) "19:45:12 25.12.13" which is very good :P Thank you very much. The date now successes to parse. maybe you should do that as answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have some "invisible" characters, you can remove them with regular expression:

```php
$last_vote_date_str = trim(preg_replace('~[^\d:.]~', ' ', $last_vote_date_str));
```

Code above will remove all characters, that are not number, `:` or `.`, with space.

Answer (score 3):

Your `var_dump()` outpu shows `string(26) "19:45:12 25.12.13"`. It should say `string(17)` instead. So, there are 9 hidden characters in your actual `$last_vote_date_str` string and that's causing the function to not work.

Add the following line of code to the top of your script and refresh the page again to check the `var_dump()` output:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

That will set the `Content-Type` of the document to plaintext and will reveal all the characters and you can easily find out what's causing the error.

Comment: Err now I see just html code of page and can't check. I read this date value from another site after entering some data to page. If I look on the html code of that page where I read date from, it's same as 19:45:12 25.12.13